# D3.js drag realtive to graph svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have code that should move a circle that's plotted on a graph in a svg using D3.js v6. The circle should be dragged to where the cursor is relative to the graph but I think the cursor position that is given is relative to the whole window and not the graph/svg. I'm not sure how to modify the mouse position to be relative to the svg. I have also tried using the suggestion from this answer here as well:

[d3 v6 pointer function not adjusting for scale and translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189608/d3-v6-pointer-function-not-adjusting-for-scale-and-translate)

Edit:

If I were to start the circle at a position such as (0.5, 0.5) how would I go about making it so the circle only moves in a path along the circumference of a circle centered at (0, 0) with radius 0.5? I tried scaling the position of the mouse to be of magnitude 0.5 using:

```
x = x*(0.5/(Math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)));
y = y*(0.5/(Math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)));
```

As this is how you scale a vector to be a certain length while keeping the same direction as shown here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897723/how-to-resize-a-vector-to-a-specific-length

However this doesn't seem to work even though it should scale any point the mouse is at to be on the circle centered at the origin with radius 0.5.

```js
var margin = {top: -20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 40};
//just setup
var svg = d3.select("#mysvg") 
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
var xAxis = d3.scaleLinear() 
    .domain([-1.5, 1.5])
    .range([0, 300]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 300 + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xAxis)); 

var yAxis = d3.scaleLinear() 
    .domain([-1.5, 1.5])
    .range([300, 0]);

svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yAxis)); 
    
var circle1 = svg.append('circle')
    .attr('id', 'circle1')
    .attr('cx', xAxis(0))
    .attr('cy', yAxis(0))
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style('fill', '#000000')
    .call( d3.drag().on('drag', dragCircle) ); //add drag listener
    
function dragCircle(event) {
    
        let x = d3.pointer(event, svg.node())[0];
        let y = d3.pointer(event, svg.node())[1];    

        console.log("x: " + x + " y: " + y);
        d3.select("#circle1")
            .attr("cx", xAxis(x))
            .attr("cy", yAxis(y));
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="mysvg"></svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things,

D3.pointer returns units in pixels, these do not need to be scaled - the purpopse of the scale is to take an arbitrary unit and convert it to pixels:

So instead of:

```
    d3.select("#circle1")
        .attr("cx", xAxis(x))
        .attr("cy", yAxis(y));
```

Try:

```
    d3.select("#circle1")
        .attr("cx", x)
        .attr("cy", y);
```

Also, we want the drag to be relative to the `g` which holds the plot and has a transform applied to it. This part is detailed in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64189608/7106086) you link to. We can specify that we want the drag to be relative to the parent `g` with:

```
    let x = d3.pointer(event,svg.node())[0];
    let y = d3.pointer(event,svg.node())[1];
```

We can then use some trigonometry to constrain the point to a ring and have the drag be based on the angle to any arbitrary point:

```
        let x = d3.pointer(event,svg.node())[0];
        let y = d3.pointer(event,svg.node())[1]; 
        
        let cx = xAxis(0);
        let cy = yAxis(0);
        let r = xAxis(0.5)-xAxis(0);
        
        let dx = x- cx;
        let dy = y-cy;
        
        var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);

        d3.select("#circle1")
            .attr("cx", cx + Math.cos(angle)*r)
            .attr("cy", cy + Math.sin(angle)*r);
```

Which gives us:

```js
var margin = {top: -20, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 40};
//just setup
var svg = d3.select("#mysvg") 
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
var xAxis = d3.scaleLinear() 
    .domain([-1.5, 1.5])
    .range([0, 300]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + 300 + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xAxis)); 

var yAxis = d3.scaleLinear() 
    .domain([-1.5, 1.5])
    .range([300, 0]);

svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yAxis)); 
    
var circle1 = svg.append('circle')
    .attr('id', 'circle1')
    .attr('cx', xAxis(0))
    .attr('cy', yAxis(0))
    .attr('r', 10)
    .style('fill', '#000000')
    .call( d3.drag().on('drag', dragCircle) ); //add drag listener
    
var dragCircle = svg.append('circle')
    .attr('id', 'circle1')
    .attr('cx', xAxis(0))
    .attr('cy', yAxis(0))
    .attr('r', xAxis(0.5)-xAxis(0))
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('stroke', 'black')
    .style('stroke-line',1)
    .call( d3.drag().on('drag', dragCircle) ); //add drag listener
    
function dragCircle(event) {
    
        let x = d3.pointer(event,svg.node())[0];
        let y = d3.pointer(event,svg.node())[1]; 
        
        let cx = xAxis(0);
        let cy = yAxis(0);
        let r = xAxis(0.5)-xAxis(0);
        
        let dx = x- cx;
        let dy = y-cy;
        
        var angle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);

        d3.select("#circle1")
            .attr("cx", cx + Math.cos(angle)*r)
            .attr("cy", cy + Math.sin(angle)*r);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.0.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="mysvg"></svg>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was also wondering something else. That I've edited into the original post

Comment: I have a follow up about something you did in your code. I noticed that when I don't include the - xAxis(0) when defining r then I get the wrong answer for the position. This leads me to think that xAxis(0) isn't always 0 even though it should map 0 to a number of pixels?

Comment: r is defined in the data units not pixel units, but the drag works in pixel units, so we need to convert r to pixels using the scale. We need to scale 0 because xAxis(0) ≠ 0 in your case (they most frequently are equal when scale domain and range both start at 0). I'm not sure if I'm following your comment exactly though.

Comment: Aren't you defining r in terms of pixels since both xAxis(0.5) and xAxis(0) are in units of pixels?

Comment: Poor choice of words in my response - the radius is *specified* as the distance between [0,0] and [0.5,0] in the data's units, we need to define `r` to be this distance in pixels.