# D3 tooltip not following the mouse

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a webpage with multiple charts using D3 and Object Oriented Programming.

Working code link--> https://codepen.io/mohan-ys/pen/LYLwqrK

The problem I am facing is that the tooltip is not at the mouse location, it is somewhere else.
I tried using `d3.event.pageX` & `d3.event.pageY` instead of `vis.mouse[0]` & `vis.mouse[1]` which is in the code above but it does not work.

I am getting the tooltip as shown. When the mouse is at the right end of the graph, the tool tip moves further right, it gets closer somewhere in the middle & it goes to the other side by the time the cursor is on the left end of the chart!

The page is resized, then it is a totally different behaviour!

Can anyone help get the tooltip right a the mouse pointer (top-left corner at the mouse pointer) for all graphs & even when the page is resized (the graphs scale with page resize).

The vertical line follows the mouse perfectly!, so, if there is another way of creating the tooltip instead of a `div`, that is also ok for me.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189608/d3-v6-pointer-function-not-adjusting-for-scale-and-translate) but the answer doesn't directly solve your problem. Basically, there's a second and optional argument to [`d3.pointer`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/main/README.md#pointer) called `target` such that:

> If target is not specified, it defaults to the source event’s
> currentTarget property, if available. If the target is an SVG element,
> the event’s coordinates are transformed using the inverse of the
> screen coordinate transformation matrix...

You can make use of this argument per below noting that it will break your vertical tracking line if you try and just update `vis.mouse`:

```
// mouse moving over canvas
vis.mouse = d3.pointer(event); // keep this for the vertical tracking line
vis.mouse2 = d3.pointer(event, d3.select(vis.chartLocation)); // <--- NEW VARIABLE!
```

Now `vis.mouse2` has a relative `x` and `y` - so use them where you set the `style` of the `div`:

```
d3
  .select(vis.chartLocation)
  .selectAll("#tooltip")
  .html((d, i) => {
    vis.xDate = d.values[vis.idx - 1].date;
    return vis.xDate.toLocaleDateString("pt-PT");
  })
  .style("display", "block")
  .style("left", vis.mouse2[0] + "px") // use vis.mouse2
  .style("top", vis.mouse2[1] + "px") // use vis.mouse2
```

The clue is in that your first selection is `vis.chartLocation`.

Comment: wow! it is as if you read my mind. The code you put is exactly what I did to have this working! working page is here https://moyscode.github.io/